# Why doesn't my self-practice code work as I intended it to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the code below to call back "great", and if it can't, I want it to continue till it can. But for some reason, if you do not write in either "go away" or "great" the loop just... stops. Could you explain to me why this happens? Because what I have just learnt tells me that it should run till the input matches the words I had put in, especially since I am using "continue"s.

I also tried using "else:" at the end of the code, same result.

```
loving = "go away"
while loving == "go away":
    print("please write in something loving")
    loving = input()
    if loving == "go away":
        print("that's a bit rude...")
        continue
    elif loving == "great":
        print("thanks mate")
    elif loving != "great":
        continue
```

no error results, it just does not work the way i thought it would.

Comment: Probably because `loving == "go away"` is no longer true. What else could it be?

Comment: The loop stops whenever the input is something other than `go away`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the loop to keep going until the user enters `great`, that's what you need to check for, rather than checking only for `go away`.

```
loving = ""
while loving != "great":
    print("please write in something loving")
    loving = input()
    if loving == "go away":
        print("that's a bit rude...")
    elif loving == "great":
        print("thanks mate")
```

Comment: ahh yeah that sounds awful simple now that you put it that way. but if this is the case, the continue's are kind of unnecessary, right? it will continue anyways?

edit: Just tried it, continue's are completely unnecessary, even if we delete the last line, it works just as how I intended it. All this confusion arose from me not knowing that you can leave a variable blank...

Comment: Yeah, there's lots of unnecessary stuff. You only need `continue` if there's something after all the `if` statements that you want to skip over. You also don't need the last `elif`, since it's just everything else and it doesn't do anything there.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter anything other than `"go away"`, the variable `loving` binds to whatever you typed, and this results in the loop ending because `loving` does not equal to `"go away"` anymore.